# calling an async function from another js file

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, mongoose

I have a function which gets all record in my collection in mongodb.

```
var getVouchers= function(){

  Customer.find({}, function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    return result;
  });     
};
```

I call like this and when I put break point, I can see that I have result. The problem is, when I call this function, it does not wait..

As it is nodejs, I exported the function as follow

```
module.exports.getVouchers =getVouchers;
```

and I call like this

```
var router = require('./api');

adminPanel.get('/', (req,res)=>
{
  router.getVouchers().then((result)=>{
    console.log(result);
  });        
});
```

and I got the following exception

> (node:26972) [DEP0016] DeprecationWarning: 'GLOBAL' is deprecated, use
>   'global'

event I do not use `GLOBAL` keyword

how to solve this problem?

edit:

I updated the my code now

```
var  getVouchers = function() {
    // `delay` returns a promise
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

    Customer.find({}, function(err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;

         return result;

      });     
    });
  }
```

and I call the function as

```
  (async function(){
        let vouchers=await router.getVouchers();
        console.log(vouchers);
      })();
```

the first function has the result but there is no return value, that means, it never comes to the console.log part.

Edit 2:

Instead of return result, as @ajuni880 said, I made  resolve(result); and it works now.

Comment: That's a *warning*, not an error

Comment: You can ignore the warning, but focus on your `getVouchers` function definition: You call it with `then` but it is neither a Promise nor declared as an async one.

Comment: @CertainPerformance thank you for the answer.. the main question is that I do not have any result

Comment: @tkausl I've updated the my code with the help of the link that you gave but still not working

Comment: You have to resolve your promise to be able to get the results

Comment: @vahdet thank you for the answer vahdet. I do not have much experience in js. I've just made it with promise, I can still get a result but no return value

Comment: @ajuni880 thank you it works now

Comment: @ajuni880, you should write an answer and I'll accept it as the correct answer.

Comment: @ertan2002 i cant write an answer its marked as duplicated.

Comment: @ajuni880 I see.. Sorry for that then.. Thank you again